# Как создать поле для временных отрезков?

Tags: python, django, django-model

У каждого рабочего может быть в день несколько рабочих отрезков, как создать для них поле?

```
from django.db import models

class Worker(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Comment: делайте другую таблицу id работника, дата, время начала, время конца

Comment: и дополню пред комментарий, свяжите таблицы одно ко многим

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто создать еще одну модель WorkTime, где я и буду хранить рабочие отрезки. Спасибо splash58 и Dmitry за помощь!